# How to upload file in android to meteor CollectionFS based web application

Tags: android, meteor, file-upload, browser, collectionfs

My meteor web app using CollectionFS.  File uploading is normally for almost all kinds of browser, except for browser from android mobile phone.

Below is a live demo of meteor CollectionFS (not mine): 
[http://collectionfs.meteor.com](http://collectionfs.meteor.com/)

Every file I uploaded from android mobile phone is corrupted and not openable. Any ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: I have added a demo on meteor:  [http://testcfs.meteor.com](http://testcfs.meteor.com), the code is from [https://github.com/middlelogic/photoUploadExample](https://github.com/middlelogic/photoUploadExample).  Again, android phone is not working for uploading photos.  Any help is much appreciated.